# How to print Back Arrow head stars pattern in C++?

Tags: c++

I made simple arrow head star pattern but I can't add spaces to create a reverse arrow head. Please help me to figure it out.

```
for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

for (k=5; k>=1; k--) {
    for (l=1; l<=k; l++) {
        cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Improved code formatting/indentation/spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=6-i;j++)
    {
        cout<<" ";
    }
    while(j!=7)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        j++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"******"<<endl;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        cout<<" ";
    }
    while(j!=7)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        j++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

**P.S.** Please refrain from asking questions in which you only have an issue forming a logic, SO community is always there to help you but we cannot cook your dishes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lot of methods.

```
int i, j;

    //6 means number of raws that you want to print
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    //5 means number of raws that you want to print
    for(i = 5; i >= 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
```

And also this

```
int i, j;

    //5 means number of raws that you want to print
    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "******"<<endl;

    //5 means number of raws that you want to print
    for(i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {
  const char clearCh = ' ';
  const char fillCh = '*';
  const size_t size = 6;

  std::string str(size, clearCh);

  for (int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    str[i] = fillCh;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < str.size() - 1; ++i) {
    str[i] = clearCh;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/8cdtg)